# Which size do I need to use in Blender to import to Unity

Tags: unity, blender

I want to create a cube with different textures in Blender. But if I import the model to Unity 2017 the cube has not the same size as a cube with scale x,y and z = 1 from Unity's default components. Which size do I need for my cube in Blender so it has the same size as a default cube in Unity?

Comment: Did you try scaling a Unity cube to match your Blender cube? That will tell you the exact scaling ratio between the two in your current setup.

Comment: Yes, but it ist hard to find the exact scale.

Comment: Are you directly importing the blend file? Or using FBX?

Comment: No, I use the blend file. But I also could import it as fbx.

Comment: well an option is to change the unit settings in blender.

Comment: Or, just importing the model as a blend file and scaling it in blender until it gets the size that you want(if you import the model as a .blend file, Unity will readjust automatically to it's changes, modifying the model in your scene)

Comment: Yes, it seems like a scale from 0.5 is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

The cube in Blender is 2 x 2 x 2m.  You need to scale that down and then apply that scale.

Here is how I handle it when exporting to Unity.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Text on those images could have been better.  Sorry, was in a rush.